# how to make Insecure connection for rest api in nifi

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I have ssl based authentication with my remote  nifi , is  there any way i can use   nifi  processors and  groovy code to make rest api commands. I have stopped  processor and  deleted bad  flowfiles in queues in simple nifi(on my desktop)  but i can't do it on remote  nifi , i can't use  ssl certificate  for connecting  server

1. Is there anyway i can get rid of authentication i don't  use  curl
   commands i want to  do it inside nifi by invokehttp processor and  groovy code

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make an unsecure request to a secure NiFi...

Each secured NiFi node already has its own certificate and truststore which you specified in nifi.properties in order to secure it. You could use this same keystore and truststore in an SSLContextService to make a secure connection back to itself.

Comment: Do  you mean  this:  ./conf/ssl/server.keystore.jks ?